# want to create XACML policy dynamically

Tags: authorization, wso2, xacml3

i am using WSo2 BALANA as my XACML authorization server .Until now i was creating XACML policies manually.however, creating a XACML policy manually is tough and also not feasible. a policy creation tool or an API with which i can create XACML policies  dynamically  would be needed to address this issue. is there any tool or api like that is available ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.. If you want to integrate policy creation in to your project using some library. I guess, best approach is to use Balana utils library. It is a library that can be used to create XACML 3.0 policies and XACML 3.0 request using an simple object model. You find the source code of Balana util from [here](http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/trunk/commons/balana/modules/balana-utils/). Basically WSO2 Identity Server policy editors are used this library to build the policies.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Asela says, you want to use the parsing libraries of the engine (PDP) you use. SunXACML has its libraries, WSO2 has its own, Axiomatics its own, and so on...

If you wanted to serialize and deserialize XACML policies to/from its XML form, you could also use JAX-B. THat would help you build XACML policies programmatically. But that would give you separate objects from what the PDPs would require.